# Change default modal antd stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I am using Tab and Popup modal from antd in my ReactJS code to display data. How do I change the CSS property from the default that is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import your css, and then it is ready to go.
An example [here][1].

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/RB_Projects/pen/MWwmPPK
```

Comment: I tried this technique with the Tab modal and it dosent work. Can you please explain how that works?